# dc.js bubble chart - multidimension grouping issue and unable to get custom reducer to work

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm currently trying to produce a dashboard in dc.js for my master's thesis and I have hit a real roadblock today if anyone could please help it would be much appreciated. I'm new to Javascript and dc so I'll try my best to explain...

My data format (Probe Request with visible SSID):

```
{"vendor":"Huawei Technologies Co.Ltd","SSID":"eduroam","timestamp":"2018-07-10 12:25:26","longitude":-1.9361,"mac":"dc:d9:16:##:##:##","packet":"PR-REQ","latitude":52.4505,"identifier":"Client"}
```

My data format (Probe Request with Broadcast / protected SSID):

```
{"vendor":"Nokia","SSID":"Broadcast","timestamp":"2018-07-10 12:25:26","longitude":-1.9361,"mac":"dc:d9:16:##:##:##","packet":"PR-REQ","latitude":52.4505,"identifier":"Client"}
```

I'm trying to produce a bubble chart which will display vendors as a bubble (size denoted by volume of packets collected for that vendor) then plot the bubble against X axis unprotected (any SSID != broadcast) & Y axis protected (packets where "Broadcast" is in the data)

Sketch of what I mean
[image: Sketch of what I mean]

What I've managed to get so far
[image: What I've managed to get so far]

I've managed to get a bar/ row/pie charts to work as they only require me to use one dimension and run them through a group. But I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to pass multiple dimensions to a group.

for each at the top adds a new value of 0 / 1 to triple if Broadcast is present in the data.

Then I'm using a custom reducer to count 0 / 1 related to unpro & pro which will be used to plot the X / Y

I've tried reworking the nasdaq example and I'm getting nowhere

Code:

```
queue()
 .defer(d3.json, "/uniquedevices")
 .await(plotVendor);

function plotVendor(error, packetsJson) {

  var packets = packetsJson;

  packets.forEach(function (d) {

    if(d["SSID"] == "Broadcast") {
      d.unpro = 0;
      d.pro = 1;
      } else {
        d.unpro = 1;
        d.pro = 0;
        }
      });

var ndx = crossfilter(packets);

var vendorDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {

return [ d.vendor, d.unpro, d.pro ];
});

var vendorGroup = vendorDimension.group().reduce(

  function (p, v) {
      ++p.count;
      p.numun += v.unpro;
      p.numpr += v.pro;
      return p;
  },

  function (p, v) {
      --p.count;
      p.numun -= v.unpro;
      p.numpr -= v.pro;
      return p;
  },

  function () {
      return {
          numun: 0,
          numpr: 0
      };
  }
);

var vendorBubble = dc.bubbleChart("#vendorBubble");
vendorBubble
    .width(990)
    .height(250)
    .transitionDuration(1500)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(vendorDimension)
    .group(vendorGroup)
    .yAxisPadding(100)
    .xAxisPadding(500)

    .keyAccessor(function (p) {
  return p.key[1];
})
    .valueAccessor(function (p) {
  return p.key[2];
})
    .radiusValueAccessor(function (d) { return Object.keys(d).length; 
})

    .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.3)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]))
    .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 20]))

dc.renderAll();

};
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adamistheanswer/tm9fzc4r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are aggregating the data right and the missing bits are

- your accessors should look inside of `value` (that's where crossfilter aggregates)

  ```
  .keyAccessor(function (p) {
    return p.value.numpr;
  })
  .valueAccessor(function (p) {
    return p.value.numun;
  })
  .radiusValueAccessor(function (d) {
    return d.value.count; 
  })
  ```
- your key should just be the vendor - crossfilter dimensions aren't geometric dimensions, they are what you filter and bin on:

  ```
  var vendorDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.vendor;
  });
  ```
- you probably need to initialize `count` because `++undefined` is `NaN`:

  ```
  function () { // reduce-init
    return {
      count: 0,
      numun: 0,
      numpr: 0
    };
  }
  ```

[image]
Fork of your fiddle, with all the dependencies added, wrapping function disabled, and elasticX/elasticY (probably not what you want but easier to debug):

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/spw5oxkj/16/

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply!

Appreciate your explanation of the dimensioning and accessors, makes much more sense then what I was attempting

I've had a go at implementing your suggestions but unfortunately it's still mangled..  I'm now getting all of the bubbles situated at (0,10) when I adjust the scale they still hop to the top left corner of the chart.

Comment: I assume this means that the v.pro & v.unpro aren't being handled properly? When I've been using these values in Numberdisplay I've had to use reduceSum for the grouping... tried this here to no avail.

Thanks, Adam

Comment: Naw, I just got the names of the fields wrong in the accessors - these should match what the group reduction produces, not the fields in the original data. Also got your fiddle working with the right dependencies, moved it to dc3 & d3v5 (just the scales - should be easy to change back if you need to use dc2), and used elasticX & elasticY to get it to all show up.

Comment: Gordon I can't thank you enough!! Just been jumping about the computer labs.. this has been such a headache to get to work.. but now you've walked me through it, I really feel like I understand the grouping procedure! You're an absolute saint

Comment: Cool! Yes, there isn't any magic to it, but it takes a little while to understand how it all fits together.